# How to make a login mechanism for a java web application?

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications, netbeans, authentication

I'm trying to make a java web application in netbeans. This project must contain jsp pages and the user must have the possibility to log in. I have no idea how to make the login mechanism. I'm using IDE netbeans , glassfish server and hibernate to connect with my mysql database.

Comment: SO isn't the place to ask for tutorials, and this isn't a question about a specific problem.

Comment: Dont create your own login mechanism. Use those provided by web server. Search for authentication and authorization for [glassfish](http://www.simtay.com/part-2-securing-web-application-glassfish-v3-jaas-authentication-and-authorization/) or [tomcat](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-use-form-authentication-with-tomcat.html). There are a lot of [factors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-form-based-website-authentication?rq=1) to consider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish your goal with [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org). This project makes it easy to implement the login mechanism that you are looking for. The "Website Login Demo" link below shows a complete demonstration. The project code offers an example as well.

See:

[Apache Shiro Website Login Example](http://shiro.apache.org/webapp-tutorial.html)

[Apache Shiro Web Support Docs](http://shiro.apache.org/web.html)